# VB.NET 2010 - MySQL Variable Assignment Warning

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Below is a simple routine to test the rollback of a transaction if there is an error. VB.NET tells me that the variable tr.Rollback() under the Catch "Variable tr.Rollback() has been used before it has been assigned a value" and also about the Public override.

As this is being used within the Try/Catch/End Try, I would have thought that it would have been assigned as per the assignment in the Try.

The program does work as expected.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

MySQL ver 5.1.36 and tables using InnoDB

Option Strict On

Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Module Module1

```
Sub Main()

    Dim cs As String = "Database=testdb;Data Source=qn-server1;" _
        & "User Id= xxxxxx"

    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection(cs)
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand()

    Dim tr As MySqlTransaction


    Try
        conn.Open()


        tr = conn.BeginTransaction()

        cmd.Connection = conn
        cmd.Transaction = tr

        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Authors SET Name = 'Leo Tolstoy' WHERE Id = 1"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Books SET Title = 'War and Peace' WHERE Id = 1"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Books SET Titl = 'Anna Karenina' WHERE Id = 2" <----- DELIBERATE ERROR on "Titl" TO TEST THE ROLL BACK I.E tr.Rollback()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        tr.Commit()
        conn.Close()

    Catch ex As MySqlException
        tr.Rollback() <------------------------------ THIS LINE "Variable "tr" has been assigned a value............. 
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " & ex.ToString())
    End Try


    Console.ReadLine()




End Sub
```

End Module

Answer (score 0):

The problem will arise if the calling of `conn.Open()` will fail. A `MySqlException` will be thrown, which iteslf again will throw an exception as the `tr` variable/object has no value.

So checking first to see if `tr` is Nothing before calling `Rollback()` method can fix this problem like:

```
Catch ex As MySqlException
    if tr IsNot Nothing Then tr.RollBack();
```

EDIT: This will not help to get rid of the warning. For this you need to initialze the `tr` variable to nothing like:

```
Dim tr As MySqlTransaction = Nothing
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the quick reply. Even with the If/Then I still have the same message from VB

Comment: To get rid of the warning you can simply initielize your `tr` variable to Nothing. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Ok but where should I initialise to Nothing as it it already defined in both the public  Dim tr As MySqlTransaction and then in the Try tr = conn.BeginTransaction()

Comment: Juast add `= Nothing` to your Dim statement.